# Text fields become unresponsive while running Java Swing JFrame after re-opening NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I created a JFrame form using Java Swing in NetBeans. It contains some text fields, some combo boxes and a button to navigate to the next form. Everything works fine until I close and re-open NetBeans. Now when I run the form only the text fields become unresponsive. The combo boxes and the button work correctly. I tried using setEditable(), setFocusable() and requestFocusinWindow() with the text fields but the output hasn't changed. Please help me.

```
package Hora.GUI;

import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class InputJFrame3 extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    public InputJFrame3()
    {
        initComponents();

        numberJTextField.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
                                          {
                                              public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
                                              {
                                              numberJTextField.setForeground(Color.black);
                                              }
                                          });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

    numberJLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    numberJTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    nextJButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("HORA");
    setFocusableWindowState(false);

    numberJLabel.setText("Number");

    nextJButton.setText("next >");
    nextJButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            nextJButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(nextJButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(numberJLabel)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(numberJTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(numberJLabel)
                .addComponent(numberJTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(nextJButton)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void nextJButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {
        //GEN-FIRST:event_nextJButtonActionPerformed
        number=Integer.parseInt(numberJTextField.getText());

        Boolean mistake=false;

        if(number<1 || number>249)
        {
            mistake=true;
            numberJTextField.setForeground(Color.red);
        }

        if(!mistake)
            setVisible(false);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_nextJButtonActionPerformed

    public int getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }

    private int number;

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton nextJButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel numberJLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField numberJTextField;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}


package Hora.GUI;

public class Run
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                InputJFrame3 frame = new InputJFrame3();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I've reviewed your code and cannot see any obvious error, and cannot reproduce your error when changing your code slightly so that I can get it to run. It may not be possible for us to identify the error based on the code as presented, and so I suggest 2 things: 1) do some debugging either using a debugger or println statements to try to isolate the bug, or 2) create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) to allow us to more easily reproduce and try to help find and fix the bug. Please read the link in its entirety since the closer you are to the sscce recipe, the better our ability to help.

Comment: Having said that, there are definitely things that I don't like in your code and recommend you change, such as your swapping JFrames on the fly, calling another class's main method. You should consider refactoring your code to get the model and control code out of your GUI code.

Comment: I changed the logic and put the control code in another class. I removed all the unnecessary part and included only a text box and a button. Still the same problem persists. Please can you run it and see?

Comment: The posted code is still not a SSCCE. Your question is about a JTextField. So post code that only contains your text field. We don't have access to the Angle class. All that code is irrelevant to your question. You also left in the declaration of 20 variables. They are also not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Yes Sir, I changed the code and included only a text field and a button. I left the generated code as it is. Please check out the updated code which I have replaced in the place of original code. - Sireesha

Comment: Sorry there was a delay in posting the code after posting the comment. You must have seen it during that time. I should have posted the code first. - Sireesha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
setFocusableWindowState(false);
```

Doing this prevents the JTextField from getting focus and being usable. I suggest that you not do this.

Also, I agree with camickr, that you should not use an IDE to create your [sscce](http://sscce.org). Just add your components to a simple JPanel which uses FlowLayout by default, something like:

```
  nextJButton.setText("next >");
  nextJButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        nextJButtonActionPerformed(evt);
     }
  });

  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  panel.add(numberJLabel);
  panel.add(numberJTextField);
  panel.add(otherJTextField);
  panel.add(nextJButton);

  getContentPane().add(panel);

  pack();
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents
```

Also and again, your program looks as if it's swapping JFrames which generally considered a weak design. Instead gear your code to create JPanel "views" and have your GUI swap views with a CardLayout. If you must show a detail window, then use a JDialog.

---

**Edit 2**
In a comment you state:

> But that part is in the generated code. I opened the java file in Wordpad and modified it. It works now. Is there any other way to do it using the IDE? Thanks a lot Mr. Hovercraft and Mr. Camickr for helping me out. I'm doing this a hobby project for my grandpa who wants to automate his astrology calculations.

I think it is fair to say that most of the main Swing advisers on this site (at least the ones that that I am familiar with) create their Swing code by hand. Don't get me wrong, we use IDE's, but we don't use an IDE's drag-and-drop tool in creating our Swing code. The [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) will help you learn how to do this. In particular, please have a look at [Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) the section.

Note that even if you do end up using a Swing code generator such as NetBeans's Matisse tool, it won't hurt you to learn how to do some hand coding since the knowledge gained will be directly applicable in your work with the code-generating tool.

Comment: +1, I would have beat you :) but I was going to add a comment about not using an IDE to create the form. Then a statement like this should not be added without the OP knowing why the statement is added.

Comment: But that part is in the generated code. I opened the java file in Wordpad and modified it. It works now. Is there any other way to do it using the IDE? Thanks a lot Mr. Hovercraft and Mr. Camickr for helping me out. I'm doing this a hobby project for my grandpa who wants to automate his astrology calculations. - Sireesha

Comment: Mr. Hovercraft, I'll surely do that. Thanks for your valuable advice. - Sireesha